# Vue create async emit with defineEmits

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am currently having a component which raises an event when a button was clicked. The parent component handles this event with an async event handler. This handler needs to be awaited in the child component.

The current declaration looks like this:

```
const emit = defineEmits<{buttonClicked: [buttonAction: string]}>()
```

When i await the emit in the child component i am getting the warning 'Refactor this redundant 'await' on a non-promise.'

```
await emit('buttonClicked', 'myAction')
```

How can i declare the buttonClicked as an async function with `defineEmits`?

Answer (score 1):

This is XY problem. Generally everything that's returned from event listeners is ignored, this includes the way Vue event handling works. It would be impossible to make `await emit(...)` work like that because event listeners and triggers aren't supposed to have 1:1 relationship.

If you rely on a promise for the correct order of execution, you may need something else. In this case a callback could be used directly inside a child instead of relying on event handling:

```
await props.handleClick('myAction')
```

Comment: I had a bug because of the execution order but with the answere i posted it works. So i don't get why awaiting the emit is impossible?

Comment: It depends on how it works in your case but the answer you posted just silences a reasonable warning and allows to use code that may not work as expected. emit doesn't return a promise, it's the same as waiting for one tick like `emit('buttonClicked', 'myAction'); await undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

To define the emits as awaitable you need to use another `defineEmits` variant which looks like the following.

```
const emit = defineEmits<{(event: 'buttonClicked', buttonAction: string): Promise<void>}>()
```